# MKMapView centerCoordinate not exact

Tags: ios, mapkit

When I try to place a pin in the center of the map using **MKMapView's centerCoordinate** it puts a pin roughly in the center, but it's several pixels south of the true center of the map.

I tried converting the map's center point to a coordinate 
**MKMapView.convertPoint(MKMapView.center)** and that worked perfectly on ios8 but on ios7 is still off (now its south and west of the true center).

Anyone know how to determine how "off" the center coordinate is so I can adjust?

I need this because I am placing a crosshair image over the map and need the pin to appear in the center of the crosshair.  I've verified with a ruler that the crosshair is centered on the map, it's the pin that is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27868564/1271826) you fixed one particular scenario where the center coordinate appears to be off, but really is not because it is just partially obscured by the status bar. Unfortunately, it is not as simple as that. There are other edge cases where the center coordinate actually can get offset a bit. (I notice it when I change frame of map view as keyboard is presented and later dismissed.) This is a curious little map view idiosyncrasy.

> Anyone know how to determine how "off" the center coordinate is so I can adjust?

Yes, just convert the `centerCoordinate` to a `CGPoint` and compare to the `center`. The only trick is to make sure you do these in the same coordinate system (in the example below, the coordinate system of the map view):

```
func adjustOverlayCenterYConstraint() {
    let mapCenter = mapView.convert(mapView.centerCoordinate, toPointTo: mapView)
    let viewCenter = mapView.superview!.convert(mapView.center, to: mapView)

    overlayCenterYConstraint.constant = mapCenter.y - viewCenter.y
}
```

In this example, I have a `centerY` constraint, whose `constant` I am adjusting, but it illustrates the idea of how to programmatically determine whether the center is offset a bit and how to adjust it. Theoretically, you might have to adjust the x coordinate, too, but the idea would be the same.

---

You said:

> is still off (now its south and west of the true center)

If it is off both south and west, then the problem is likely just the coordinate system. Remember, `center` is in the coordinate system of the `superview`, so make sure to convert to a consistent coordinate system (either get `coordinateCenter` in coordinate system of map view’s `superview` and compare to `center`, or get both in the coordinate system of the mapview, like shown above).

Comment: This is a _fantastic_ answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Well I still don't know why in iOS7 MKMapView.convertPoint(MKMapView.center) differs from MKMapView.centerCoordinate, but did figure out why .centerCoordinate was off.

Part of the map was under the status bar and I ruled the center based on the visible part and overlaying images centered on the visible part, but the map computed center based on the whole map.  So once I fixed the map not running under the status bar .centerCoordinate works and, on iOS7, works better than MKMapView.center.